# What is the best SVN GUI interface program for Sun Solaris UNIX?

Tags: unix, svn, gui, solaris

I have SVN installed on another server and I want to access it on Solaris. Please give me idea how to do it? Is there any tools available?

Answer (score 4):

I was a [**RapidSVN**](http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/) guy before I discovered [**Bazaar Explorer**](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/explorer/en/):

[image]

Both are great though. I'd strongly suggest learning the command-line as well once you get the time, you won't regret it!

Comment: Bazaar Explorer has nothing to do with SVN. With CVS but not with SVN.

Comment: @BeowulfOF: [how-to use bazaar on subversion projects](http://doc.bazaar-vcs.org/migration/en/foreign/bzr-on-svn-projects.html) suggests any bazaar client can handle SVN.

Comment: Yup. Thanks for the unqualified downvote @Beowulf.

Answer (score -1):

You could try [RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/) as it is created like RapidSVN but works for multiple VCS.

RapidSVN works a bit static for my taste. For most cases I would look after a plugin for my IDE to work with SVN.